# Multiple Modal on Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create a table with 3 modal, in the same row i have 2 buttons, delete and details that will open each modal, and the whole line is a other button that will open the edit modal.

The problem is: when i click on delete or view button, open 2 modal, the edit modal and delete modal.

Example:

```
<!--Table-->
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit" >
    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete">Delete Button</td>
    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetails">Details Button</td>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>

<!--Modal Edit-->  
<div class="modal" id="modalEdit">
    Edit informations
</div>

<!--Modal Details-->    
<div class="modal" id="modalDetails">
    Details informations
</div>

<!--Modal Delete-->    
<div class="modal" id="modalDelete">
    Delete informations
</div>
```

When i click on row its OK, but when i click on button edit or delete, this open 2 modal, always the edit modal stay over delete ou details modal.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is since your `delete` and `details` buttons are inside the `tr`, a click on the button will bubble up to the top and fire the `row` click event also. To fix that you should prevent `event propagation` in button clicks. You have to remove `data attributes` to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<td data-toggle="modal" id="deleteBtn">Delete Button</td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#deleteBtn").on("click", function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   $("#modalDelete").modal("show");
});
```

Same should apply to the details button as well.
You can read more on event propagation here.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 0):

Following table structure will solve your issue

```
<tr>
 <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete">Delete Button</td>
 <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetails">Details Button</td>
 <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit">Edit Button</td>
 <td>Id</td>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td>Description</td>
 <td>Price</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i tryng to do without change the structure

Comment: then you will need prevent event propagation on details and delete button clicks as suggested by @thusitha